# qualRegex code to count 4 decimal

Tags: javascript, html

qualRegex returns to `false` and `true`. I used the code `^([0-9]{9})$` to check if the SIN number is 9 digit. I need code to count 4 decimal. So if any number has more than 4 decimal then will return `false`. What will be code to count 4 decimal.

Comment: Hello - it is somewhat unclear what you are asking.  Could you possibly rephrase, and give an example of both good and bad input?

Answer (score 0):

Is this regex you need?

```
^\d+\.\d{0,4}$
```

```js
const regex = /^\d+\.\d{0,4}$/gm;
const str = `24.1
24.12
24.123
24.1234
25.12345
25.123737`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```